# How to customize/style/theme the output of a custom content type in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-content-types

I am creating an own Drupal 8 "classy" sub-theme. Now I created a content type called "s-box" with some textfields. I also created a view called "scol" that is a list of "s-box". This "scol" is added as a block to the site's sidebar.

That works out well (that means everything is displayed) but I want some of the content types fields to be nested in specific markup (like the headline in h4). Preferably, I want to customize the whole output for this content type "s-box".

But I can't figure out, what the name of the twig ought to be. So far I tried:

```
node--s-box.html.twig (what I thought would be the correct name)  
block--scol.html.twig  
field--node--s-box.html.twig  
field--s-box.html.twig  
node--scol.html.twig  
scol--s-box.html.twig
```

Perfect solution would be a template, where I can build my own html and assign the content type's fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply enable *Twig Debugging*. See [Debugging Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates). After you've enabled Twig Debugging you'll get template naming suggestion printed as HTML comments directly into your markup. There you'll see how this template is supposed to be named exactly.

---

Your `sites/development.services.yml` is supposed to look like following:

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
      debug: true
      auto_reload: true
      cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

And you need to add the following line to your `settings.php` or `settings.local.php`:

```
/**
 * Enable local development services.
 */
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
```

Which will in the end give you something like that:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * node--page--j1.html.twig
   * node--1--full.html.twig
   * node--1.html.twig
   * node--page--full.html.twig
   * node--page.html.twig
   * node--full.html.twig
   x node.html.twig
-->
```

---

#### And don't forget to clear the caches! Multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! I had this already enabled but now you're pointing this out again I found the solution. I didn't notice that I can access all fields in "views-view-fields.html.twig".

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

Since my content type is in a view, I can access all fields in `views-view-fields--[my-view].html.twig`(in my case: `views-view-fields--scol.html.twig`)

Key is the `fields` array. I can access all fields by their machine name. Like `fields.title.content` or `fields.field_foo.content`.

Thus I can style the whole output of a s-box here.